# Converting a positive whole number of length 12 to a unique alphanumeric of length 10

Tags: radix

Would it be ok to do this by base conversion from base 10?  If so, which would be the best base to convert to in order to restrict the length of the generated string to 10 characters maximum?

Thanks

Comment: This question on math.stackexchange.com discusses the algorithm for base conversion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313954/number-base-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hexadecimal would suit your neeeds.

The largest 12 digit number `999999999999` in hexadecimal is [`e8d4a50fff`](https://www.google.dk/search?q=999999999999+in+hex) which is only ten characters.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest 12-character number in base 10 is 999 999 999 999.

A little snippet in ruby shows that the smallest base you can use to be sure to have a 10-character string is base 16, or hexadecimal:

```
1.9.3-p194 :044 > 999999999999.to_s(15)
 => "1b02b766469" 
1.9.3-p194 :045 > 999999999999.to_s(15).length
 => 11 
1.9.3-p194 :046 > 999999999999.to_s(16)
 => "e8d4a50fff" 
1.9.3-p194 :047 > 999999999999.to_s(16).length
 => 10
```